# Comb problem in Topology

Tags: general-topology

> Define a set $B$ in the real numbers as the union of $0$ and all points $1/n$ if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $X=B\times [0,1]$. $X$ has a relative topology with the subset of the plane. Prove $C=\{0\}\times[0,1]$ is a component, closed in $X$ but not open in $Y$.

I have so far but don't know how to form it into a proof:

It is basically the comb without the base of it. I want to prove the last piece/tooth is a component the is closed and not open. If I call this piece $C$, then it is not only connected but is pathwise connected. Assume $C$ is in $B$ where $C$ doesn't equal $B$. Another "tooth" $r$ exists in $B$ but doesn't equal $C$. $B$ is connected and is the max connected set where the entire "tooth" containing $r$ is a component. Since $B$ contains $r$ union $g$ where $g$ is  the compliment of $R$ and $R$ is the tooth containing $r$. Since $B$ has a point in $R$, $B$ contains $R$ is a contradiction $C$ contains $B$ contains $R$ proves it is a component.

If anyone can give any insight it would be appreciated or can give me any hints as to what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. In particular, type `\cup` to get $\cup$, `\cap` to get $\cap$, `\supset` to get $\supset$, `\subset` to get $\subset$, `A\setminus B` to get $A\setminus B$, `\times` to get $\times$, etc. Note that all of these have to be inside dollar signs, e.g. `$(A\times B)\setminus (C\cup D)$` to get $(A\times B)\setminus (C\cup D)$.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean when you say "$B$ (...) is the max connected set where [$R$] is a component". Do you mean $B$ is the component containing $C$ which you assume to contain also $R$? Please be more careful about your grammar. Also you never define $P$. Note that somewhere in your proof you must use the openness of some sets.

Comment: B is connected because it is the entire set of the "comb" without the base, so it is the maximum connected set (all the teeth) where since r is one of those teeth it is contained in B

Comment: the P was supposed to be R....sorry for the mixup

Comment: Then why assume that $C$ is in $B$, if it is a subset anyway? And in your definition of $X$ you defined $B$ as the sequence and $X$ as the entire space. Your post is pretty confusing as it contains sentences which are just dependent clauses of miss the full stop. You'd do well to clarify what you mean.

Comment: What is $Y$? ${}$

Comment: @MattN.: Almost certainly a typo for $X$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $C$ is connected. You should have no trouble showing that every open set in the plane that meets $C$ also meets $X\setminus C$ and hence that $C$ is not open in $X$. All that remains is to show that if $C\subsetneqq B\subseteq X$, then $B$ is not connected.

Suppose that $C\subsetneqq B\subseteq X$. Then there are an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and a $\beta\in[0,1]$ such that $\left\langle\frac1n,\beta\right\rangle\in B\setminus C$. Choose any $\alpha\in\left(0,\frac1n\right)\setminus B$, and let

$$L=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in B:x<\alpha\}\quad\text{and}\quad R=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in B:x>\alpha\}\;.$$

Then show that $L$ and $R$ are a separation of $B$, which therefore is not connected.